# Alternative to 2-way ANOVA when variances are unequal

Tags: anova, heteroscedasticity, nonparametric

I'm working on a question on 2-way ANOVA where there are 2 treatments and 1 blocking factor. The residual plots suggest unequal variance. What is another parametric or non-parametric alternative method to 2-way ANOVA?

Comment: If you have one blocking factor and one other factor, then [Friedman test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test) is the non-parametric alternative to classical 2-way ANOVA with blocks. How did you assess variance heterogeneity? Usually, variance tests are conducted after having accounted for block effect (i.e., tests are performed on raw data adjusted for block means).

Comment: The generalized p-value approach: http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/a7n35.pdf

Answer (score 2):

ANOVA is equivalent to regression using categorical (aka "dummy" or "indicator") variables. So any techniques from regression can also be applied to ANOVA. Here are some suggestions:

- If the error terms appear to be normally distributed, you could try using weighted least squares.
- If the error terms are not normally distributed, you would probably need to transform the variables.